# Changing value on appSettings webconfig. Only works on second pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, appsettings, webconfigurationmanager

I have below code running. Changing an appSetting in my webconfig. But I have to make a extra pageload to "make the magic".

1st. pageload. uses previous setting.
second pageload. Okay.

I have it placed inside `Page_PreInit` :

```
    Configuration configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    AppSettingsSection appSettings = (AppSettingsSection)configuration.GetSection("appSettings");

    appSettings.Settings["FileManager"].Value = "newValue";
    configuration.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the codes that run after This code by "first page load" this is something normal.
Config file just lunches after a request **(and before preInit)**.
i think the only solution is making that extra page load.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This sounds like a ninja trick... Can you tell me how to do that programmatically

Comment: you can use Response.Redirect("Page url.aspx?back=currentpageurl") and set it to come back with a request param like "currentpage.aspx?isback=1" and check for that in the page_preInt to run the code you want after it